# refer to an image with an array content

Tags: java, android

how is it possible to refer to an image with an array index at the end of the image name? Here is the code i would like to work (doesnt though...:()

```
for (int i = 0; i < melodiToner.length; i++)

setImageResource(R.drawable.gronpil+melodiToner[i]);
```

i.e I would like to load image `gronpil1.png` in the first loop, `gronpil2.png` in the second.
This isnt relative to the array content, I need some other file name endings so i cannot use the i variable, it has to be from the array.

Thanks for all help!

Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way (short version):

```
for (int i = 0; i < melodiToner.length; i++) {
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("gronpil"+melodiToner[i], "drawable", getPackageName());
    setImageResource(resId);
}
```

Longer version as to not call getResources and getPackageName once in every loop:

```
Resources resources = getResources();
String packageName = getPackageName();
for (int i = 0; i < melodiToner.length; i++) {
    int resId = resources.getIdentifier("gronpil"+melodiToner[i], "drawable", packageName);
    setImageResource(resId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create array of integer

```
int[] img = new int[5];

img[0] = R.drawable.no1;
img[1] = R.drawable.no2;
img[2] = R.drawable.no3;
img[3] = R.drawable.no4;
img[4] = R.drawable.no5;

(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    imgView.setImageResource(img[i]);
}
```